# How to get to Hunga Tonga-Hunga Ha'apai - The newest island on earth

Tags: sea-travel, islands, pacific-ocean, volcanoes, tonga

A few years back, Hunga Tonga-Hunga Ha'apai was created from a volcanic explosion:
[image]

It has since solidified, and life is beginning to pop up all around the island.

Multiple scientists and some individuals have managed to venture out there.

My question is, how would one even begin to get there? It's already quite a trek just to get out to Tonga itself, let alone venturing out 30 or so km into the sea to a desolate island.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually allowed to go there?

Comment: @gerrit: Technically speaking, according to the territorial claims made by Taufaʻahau Tupou in 1972 (which is what's legally binding), even if anyone in Tonga whom you ask will tell you differently, the isle is no man's territory (too far out for being "Tonga", if only by a couple of kilometers). So... actually, who _could_ disallow it.

Comment: @Damon Let's go there and claim it then! ;-)

Comment: Here is the google maps link. 
 https://www.google.com/maps/place/Hunga+Ha%60apai+Island/@-20.5468701,-175.4078544,6861m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x71f31183dfa1b845:0x6c47260922ebf438!8m2!3d-20.5501607!4d-175.4092697?hl=en

Comment: @gerrit: Sure, let's go. It's just what China is just trying with a rock that isn't even above the surface but would conveniently expand their territory by a hundred or so miles (and what Korea does with 독도, much to the dislike of Japan). Only just... there's a practical matter insofar as my personal army probably isn't large enough to deal with the army of Tonga. Allegedly, they have around 27,000 fit for service, and one armored ship which is a mere 27,000 soldiers and one armored ship more than I have. No problem?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_new_islands, Hunga Tonga-Hunga Haʻapai  is not the "the newest island on earth".

Comment: @gerrit didn't work out so well last time someone tried to do that to Tonga https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Minerva

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Private yacht.

COO of my previous company would sail from NZ to Fiji and back.  Often people like this enjoy the company of another person on the boat.

So either...get your own yacht, train and learn how to sail..

or, charter one from Tonga, for a fee, presumably

or, on websites like findacrew.net, see if someone else might be interested in a similar trip, and you could share the cost in exchange for you say, cooking on the boat.

Hurry tho, estimates are that [it may only be around for 7-30 years](https://www.nzherald.co.nz/travel/news/article.cfm?c_id=7&objectid=12201025).

Could also try posting on a subreddit like [this person did on /r/sailing](https://www.reddit.com/r/sailing/comments/7j8smu/anyone_sailing_to_hunga_tongahung_haapai_first/), although it doesn't look like they had much luck.

Comment: Do you know if people are actually allowed to go there without a special permit?  It sounds fragile.

Comment: @gerrit there was a 20km exclusion zone during the eruption, but not any more. I don't think it's going to be around long. I'd be checking Tongan law first tho.

Comment: @MarkMayo Damon's comment to the original question suggests that Hunga Tonga-Hunga Ha’apai is not within the area claimed as national territory by Tonga. Your comment suggests Tonga might, however, assert control. The lawyer in me is sitting back and munching popcorn.

Answer (score 9):

You could look into doing the [SEA Semester Program](https://www.sea.edu/about_sea/why_sea). While there is no guarantee that Hunga Tonga would be included, according to [NASA](https://blogs.nasa.gov/earthexpeditions/2019/01/30/land-ho-visiting-a-young-island/), one of their ships, the SSV Robert C. Seamans, was among the ships to visit the island in October, 2018.

[image: The SSV Robert C. Seamans of SEA Semester program at Hunga Tonga-Hunga Ha’apai in October, 2018. Credit: Dan Slayback]

The SSV Robert C. Seamans of SEA Semester program at Hunga Tonga-Hunga Ha’apai in October, 2018. Credit: Dan Slayback